# Database not Open Error ORA-01109

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create database using Oracle 11g on Linux, when I run script to create database instance I will get the following error message

```
ERROR at line 1: ORA-01109: database not open
```

and I'm logged in as administrator.

Comment: Are you really creating a database (with dbca)? And what does "windows linux" mean? That combination doesn't make *any* sense.

Answer (score 2):

Your database is not open.  This means it is not in a fully operative state, and you cannot run (most) DDL commands until it is open.  It might be mounted.

```
select status from v$instance;
```

In which case you can open it with the command:

```
alter database open;
```

However, if you - or whoever is DBA - didn't deliberately mount the database there will be a pressing reason why it didn't open on startup.  That needs to be investigated: there should be some information in the alert log.  You won't be able to open the database until you resolve the underlying issue.

Comment: Its already opened but still getting the same error while making connection in Oracle SQL Developer software. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70706962/oracle-db-service-is-already-opened-but-still-getting-database-not-open-error